# Getting key name from keycode (X11 XGrabKey)

Tags: c++, qt, x11

I have a global key event handler in linux as below. I need to know which keyboard is grabbed. For example if key 'P' is pressed I get the corresponding key code. Is there any way to get the key name ("P") from this unsigned key code ?

```
#include <xcb/xcb.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

#include <QtX11Extras/QX11Info>

void EventFilter::setup(QWidget *target)
{
    this->target = target;

    Display * display = QX11Info::display();
    unsigned int modifiers = ControlMask;
    keycode = XKeysymToKeycode(display, XK_A);
    XGrabKey(display, keycode, modifiers, DefaultRootWindow(display), 1, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync);
}

bool EventFilter::nativeEventFilter(const QByteArray &eventType, void *message, long *)
{
    if (eventType == "xcb_generic_event_t")
    {
        xcb_generic_event_t* xcbevent = static_cast<xcb_generic_event_t *>(message);

        switch(xcbevent->response_type)
        {
        case XCB_KEY_PRESS:
            xcb_key_press_event_t * keypress_event = static_cast<xcb_key_press_event_t *>(message);
            if(keypress_event->state & XCB_MOD_MASK_CONTROL)
            {
                if(keypress_event->detail == keycode)
                {
                    //print key name here
                }
            }
        }
    }
   return false;
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SO: How to map a X11 KeySym to a Unicode character?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8970098/7478597).

Comment: As this is tagged [tag:qt], the following may be of interest as well: [SO: How to construct Qt::Key out of KeySym or KeyCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48592348/7478597)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a key code, from the event `detail` field, you can get the `KeySym` using the `XkbKeycodeToKeysym` function, then a textual representation of the pressed key, passing the `KeySym` to the `XKeysymToString` function.

Have this extra include:

```
#include <X11/XKBlib.h>
```

Then, in the event handler:

```
case XCB_KEY_PRESS:
    xcb_key_press_event_t * keypress_event = static_cast<xcb_key_press_event_t *>(message);           
    xcb_keycode_t code = keypress_event->detail;
    qDebug() << XKeysymToString( XkbKeycodeToKeysym(QX11Info::display(), code, 0, 0) );
```

In the example above, an index of `0` is passed as the last argument of `XkbKeycodeToKeysym`. This will return the symbol for the pressed key as if the  shift key (or caps lock, or any other modifier key) is not pressed. Passing an index of `1` will return the symbol as if the shift key was pressed. Other values (i.e. `2`) will yield symbols one obtains pressing more modifier keys (e.g. in my italian keyboard I have to press *Alt Gr* to type square brackets).

Please notice, the returned string is really a **name** to identify the keyboard symbol, which can be, for example, `a`, `b`, `c` or `X` for letters, but `comma`, or `backslash` for other symbols.